# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'decimal.Decimal'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Following is the error:

```
File "F:\Coding Related\Karmachari-BackEnd\Karmachari_App\mainapp\models.py", line 97, in calculate_net_salary
    gross_pay = self.hours_worked * self.basic_pay_rate
                
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'decimal.Decimal'
These are the lasted error message in terminal.
```

models.py

```
class Payroll(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    basic_pay_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, default=10000, decimal_places=2)
    overtime = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,null=True, decimal_places=2)
    hours_worked = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    deductions = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,null=True, decimal_places=2)
    net_pay = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,null=True, blank=True, decimal_places=2)

    def calculate_net_salary(self):
        gross_pay = self.hours_worked * self.basic_pay_rate
        net_pay = gross_pay + self.overtime - self.deductions
        self.net_pay.save()

    # def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #     self.net_salary = self.calculate_net_salary()
    #     super(Payroll, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

views.py

```
def payroll(request):
    payrolls = Payroll.objects.all()
    for payroll in payrolls:
        payroll.calculate_net_salary()
    user_object = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user_object)
    context={
        'profile':profile,
        'navbar':'salary',
        'payroll': payroll,
    }
    return render(request,'Salary_Sheet.html',context)
```

I want to access payroll of each employee and calculate net salary and provide them in pdf.
This is my first project so I dont know the concept clearly and want a beginner friendly explanation or solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is very clear: You are trying to multiply a `None` and a `Decimal`.

I'm guessing `self.hours_worked` is `None`.

A dirty way to solve this issue would be to simply use zero when this value is `None`:

```py
gross_pay = (self.hours_worked or 0) * self.basic_pay_rate
```

But I'd recommend not doing this as this leads to unnecessary code pollution.

Better way to do this is not to use `null=True` but, instead, set `default=0` in your numeric model fields. Eg:

```
hours_worked = models.FloatField(default=0, blank=True)
```

You'll also need to reapply your migrations.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you that you are trying to multiply `None` with a Decimal value in your `calculate_net_salary()` method. This means that the `self.hours_worked` attribute is `None` when you are trying to calculate the `gross_pay`. You can add a check to see if `self.hours_worked` is not `None` before calculating `gross_pay`.

Better way to add `default=0`, like so:

```py
hours_worked = models.FloatField(default=0, blank=True)
```